# Default permissions of all files in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, ownership

I executed the below command.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME/
```

Now I'm not able to edit preferences in the terminal. Some weird things are also happening like some app images in the home directory are gone, I can't use conda. Can I reset to previous settings? Please help.

Comment: What is/was the value of $HOME? and what was the directory this was issued from?

Comment: No, there are no "previous settings"  to reset, unless you have a backup. However, the command should be generally harmless: not owning files in your home folder is an exception rather than the rule.  Do `echo $USER` and `echo $HOME` to verify that these have the right values.

Comment: but if $HOME was empty... and it can be... he has a problem

Comment: If `$HOME` is empty, only a complete reinstall will help.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for replying. 
Value of $HOME is /home/shane